# Getting nullpointer exception in my code

Tags: android

I am making a contact list application. I have a button called search button and when it is clicked,  am reading the name written in textbox and searching the database here is my code:

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {

public DatabaseAdapter db;
public ArrayList<String> myList;
public ListView listview;
private TextView view;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    db = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    getSearchResults();
    //getAllContacts();
    printList();
}

public void getSearchResults(){
    db.open();
    db.getContactbyName(view.getText().toString());
    Cursor c = db.getContactbyName(view.getText().toString());
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            DisplayContact(c);

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();

}

public void printList(){

    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactcListView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void getAllContacts() {
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            DisplayContact(c);

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
}

public void DisplayContact(Cursor c) {

    String entry = "";
    // if you add another attribute to your table, you need to change 3 into x
    for (int i=1; i<5;i++){
        entry += c.getString(i) + "\n";
    }
    myList.add(entry);
}
}
```

In my code, getAllContacts() method works fine and prints all the contacts. But when i try to search a contact i get a nullpointer exception and application shuts down. Can anyone see the problem?

And here is the log cat:

[image]

Thanks

Here is another version of logcat if you cannot read it :)

```
03-26 11:52:37.983: D/dalvikvm(12524): GC_CONCURRENT freed 78K, 7% free 12818K/13703K,     
paused 10ms+3ms, total 45ms
03-26 11:52:37.988: D/AbsListView(12524): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
03-26 11:52:37.993: I/MotionRecognitionManager(12524):   .unregisterListener : /     
listener count = 0->0, listener=android.widget.AbsListView$4@42464368
03-26 11:55:53.778: I/Process(12524): Sending signal. PID: 12524 SIG: 9
03-26 11:56:42.238: E/SensorManager(13254): thread start
03-26 11:56:42.238: D/SensorManager(13254): registerListener :: handle = 0  name=     
LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener=    
android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@4243e698
03-26 11:56:42.308: D/SensorManager(13254): unregisterListener::  Listener=     
android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@4243e698
03-26 11:56:42.308: D/Sensors(13254): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
03-26 11:56:42.308: I/Sensors(13254): sendDelay --- 200000000
03-26 11:56:42.308: D/SensorManager(13254): JNI - sendDelay
03-26 11:56:42.308: I/SensorManager(13254): Set normal delay = true
03-26 11:56:42.333: D/SensorManager(13254): registerListener :: handle = 0  name=    
LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener=   
android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@4243e698
03-26 11:56:43.808: D/SensorManager(13254): registerListener :: handle = 0  name=   
LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= 
android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42474b30
03-26 11:56:43.823: D/dalvikvm(13254): GC_CONCURRENT freed 119K, 7% free 12450K/13319K, 
paused 2ms+2ms, total 21ms
03-26 11:56:43.823: D/dalvikvm(13254): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
03-26 11:56:43.843: D/SensorManager(13254): unregisterListener::  Listener=   
android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42474b30
03-26 11:56:43.843: I/SensorManager(13254): Set min delay = 200000
03-26 11:56:43.843: I/SensorManager(13254): Before sending... delay = 200000
03-26 11:56:43.843: D/Sensors(13254): Remain listener = 
android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@4243e698
03-26 11:56:43.843: I/Sensors(13254): sendDelay --- 200000000
03-26 11:56:43.843: D/SensorManager(13254): JNI - sendDelay
03-26 11:56:43.848: D/SensorManager(13254): unregisterListener::  Listener= 
android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@4243e698
03-26 11:56:43.848: D/Sensors(13254): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
03-26 11:56:43.848: I/Sensors(13254): sendDelay --- 200000000
03-26 11:56:43.848: D/SensorManager(13254): JNI - sendDelay
03-26 11:56:43.848: I/SensorManager(13254): Set normal delay = true
03-26 11:56:43.873: D/SensorManager(13254): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= 
LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= 
android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42474b30
03-26 11:56:44.003: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13254): getSelectedText on inactive 
InputConnection
03-26 11:56:44.003: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13254): setComposingText on inactive 
InputConnection
03-26 11:56:44.003: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13254): getExtractedText on inactive 
InputConnection
03-26 11:56:45.658: D/AbsListView(13254): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-26 11:56:45.673: D/AndroidRuntime(13254): Shutting down VM
03-26 11:56:45.673: W/dalvikvm(13254): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught   
exception (group=0x417922a0)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to 
start activity 
ComponentInfo{cs306.hw2.database/cs306.hw2.database.SearchResultsActivity}:    
java.lang.NullPointerException 03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native   Method)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at     
s306.hw2.database.SearchResultsActivity.getSearchResults(SearchResultsActivity.java:34)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at 
cs306.hw2.database.SearchResultsActivity.onCreate(SearchResultsActivity.java:27)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at  
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
03-26 11:56:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(13254):    ... 11 more
```

And here is the layour file

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contactcListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you include your stack trace?

Comment: Sorry, i am a beginner and what is stack trace?

Comment: please show us you logfile...

Comment: How can i show it, i do not know?

Comment: I think, then this application is a bit too heavy for you, isn't it? But: When you're launching the Application in Eclipse, open `Window > Show View > Other > Log Cat`. There you can see the error output.

Comment: Post your layout code or Logcat error.

Comment: wtf? :) are you able to read that???

Comment: I think duffymo is right. I think I recognized the word ComponentInfo in your log. please show us you layout xml too.

Comment: Ok, i added the layout also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no

```
view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

in your layout xml defined.
`view` must be null.

you get the NPE here I think:

```
Cursor c = db.getContactbyName(view.getText().toString());
```

please try it with that:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contactcListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/textView1"/>
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i=0 contains id info, and i dont want to print it. I just print name, address phone and e-mail

Comment: you are right, there is no textWiew1 in this xml file but here is what i do: I have another xml layout file where i have a textbox that user enters the name to be searched. Then this layout file that i have given is loaded when user presses search button. So, since the textbox is given in the other xml file, i declared texView1 in that xml file. Am i doing wrong?

Comment: I figured it out, that was not the mistake but helped me to find it. So, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This line looks like a problem to me:

```
 listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactcListView);
```

What is "contactcListView"?  I don't see such a thing declared anywhere.

NPE is one of the easiest issues to solve.  The stack trace tells you the file and line number at which it occurred.  All you have to do is find which reference is null and why.

Comment: it is in the layout file, i think it is not a problem because getAllContacts() method works fine

Comment: You think wrong.  Stop thinking that every thing is "fine" - you'll solve your problem faster that way.

Comment: ok, thanks. I added also the xml file, can you have a look again?

Answer (score 0):

Open ddms prospective and run application

copy the logs